# Cut/Copy + Paste network files in Windows Explorer periodically stops working

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, copy-paste

On Windows 7 and 8 I have a periodic problem where cut (or copy - from here on I will just say "copy")/paste operations fail.  The copy process actually doesn't even initiate.  Here's what I mean:

- If initiated via the keyboard with a CTRL+C on a network file and subsequently CTRL+V to paste, nothing happens.  If I do a right-click the `Paste` menu option grayed out
- If I right-click on a network file, select `Copy` and subsequently right-click to paste that file, the `Paste` menu option is grayed out just as above
- Whether I use the keyboard or mouse to initiate a cut operation, the file does not gray out it should

It's as if the copy isn't registering.  I am unable to consistently reproduce the problem.  When the problem starts it is never resolved until at least the next reboot, but it often persists across several reboots.  The network server is Windows Server 2003.  This problem happens regardless of the copy destination being network or local.

Enabling/disabling antivirus has no effect.

Comment: When you do it the second time with the same source file and the same destination folder, does it work? If no - it could be a security issue, e.g. if one of your Explorer windows is elevated another one is not and/or when you don't have permission to read source or write destination.

Comment: @Scoonts - you make some interesting points. To eliminate the permissions issue and the elevation issue I am limiting my testing to even the same folder and the problem exists.

Comment: (1) Are you sure the folder's not read only? (2) Ctrl+C/V might be affected by your current input language? (3) Take a look at the 2 last posts here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itproxpsp/thread/368599c9-7304-436e-a31d-f87bb40622e8/ (by Kadan and Scott1281)

Answer (score 0):

in the run dialog, type

```
cmd /c "echo off | clip"
```

if in a command prompt already, type

```
echo off | clip
```

taken from here:
http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/141940-clear-clipboard-shortcut-create-windows.html

I know this is late, but I hope it helps someone at least   :)

It worked for me, after i ran out of memory and it stopped working. Hopefully it works for you if it happens in future.

Otherwise, try making a autohotkey script that emulates copy and paste as a workaround.